# How to generate random words in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)

OK, so I have three variables here, each being rock, paper or scissors. Using JavaScript, how can I generate one of those words randomly?

So far it's like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Click me</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                var c="Rock";
                var d="Paper";
                var e="Scissors";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I'll have a variable called K, which will be the random word out of rock paper or scissors. So it'll be like so:

```
alert("The computer chose: " + k);
```

So how can I make JavaScript select randomly between the three variables, `c`, `d` and `e`?

Comment: Put them in an *array* then select a *random index* from the array. (Please look up the emphasized words.)

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Comment: Given that OP didn't have an array in his question, I don't think the duplicate is well chosen (this being said, there are probably other similar questions).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use:

```
var things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
alert('The computer chose:' + thing);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/1/)

---

Just to precisely answer your question, supposing you really want to keep your three global variables, you could do this:

```
var c = "Rock";
var d = "Paper";
var e = "Scissors";
var thing = window['cde'.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
document.write('The computer chose: ' + thing);
```

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/rockpaperscissor.html)

(But don't.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Math.random()` to get a random number beteween 0 and 1.

If you want a whole random number between 0 and 2. (so: 0, 1 or 2). You can use:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
```

Note that `Math.round` (instead of `floor`) would be **wrong** here since the edge values will have a lower chance, and you might actually get `3` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an array:

```
var words = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
```

and then generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array, with 0 decimals:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
```

And then select the word where the key is the random number you just created:

```
var word = words[number];
```

In total:

```
var words = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
```

Comment: `-1` is not necessary.  If you add that, it would never return `Scissors` and instead return `undefined`.

Comment: If fact, if you leave the -1 in the code, you will get NaN results about 1/words.length proportion of the time. I have removed the -1 from the short summary at the end.